# how to make a space on 2 fluid columns

Tags: css

I have 2 buttons and the width is 50% each. (Fluid buttons) 
If I want to make a 10px of space between the buttons (Fixed width space)
Is there any simple way to do ?

This is my code

```
<div class="btnWrap">
    <a href="#" class="btnGray">No</a>  
    <a href="#" class="btnOrange" data-rel="back">Yes</a> 
</div> 

.btnWrap { text-align:center; overflow:hidden;  margin:0 auto;    }
.btnWrap .btnOrange { display:block; float:left; width:50%; height:36px;  }
.btnWrap .btnGray { display:block; float:left; width:50%; height:36px;  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJ73C/

```
.btnWrap { text-align:center; overflow:hidden;  margin:0 auto;    }
.btnWrap .btnOrange { display:block; float:left;  width:calc(50% - 5px); height:36px; background-color:orange; }
.btnWrap .btnGray { display:block; float:left; width:calc(50% - 5px); height:36px; background-color:gray;  }

.btnWrap a:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    margin-right: 5px;    
}

.btnWrap a:nth-of-type(even)
{
    margin-left: 5px;    
}
```

You can set the button width to 50% minus 5 pixels (5 + 5 = 10) by using `calc(50% - 5px)`

and then set a margin of 5px on the right of the left button and 5px on the left of the right.

Comment: you're welcome! Well, the margin is what works the magic of pushing them apart. Reducing the width by 5px on each button prevents the buttons from taking up more than 100% of the total width. You could also try setting float to left on the left button and float right on the right button with the width:calc

Comment: I have a question about your answer.  "width:calc(50% - 5px)" is this css3 and only support for chrome and IE9+ ?

Comment: i think this table outlines what supports this feature: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake that deleted my question T_T And thanks for your answer :)